# Get city value based on user_id from database Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel

I need to get the value from the `table - privacy_settings`, `column - city`, based on `user_id` which is on my view   `{{ $user['id'] }}`  from table `users`, column `id`.

Here is my controller :

```
    public function findUser($role = null,$search = null,$name = null,$country = null,$city = null,$industry = null,$department = null,$function_name = null,$timeframe =null,$language_skills = null,$organization_type = null,$contact_level = null,$page = null)
    {
        // if($page == "")
        // {
        //     return redirect('find-user/'.Input::get('role').'/'.Input::get('search').'/1');
        // }
        // return $role;

            // if($page == "")
            // {
            //     $page = 1;
            // }

            $data = $this->data;
            $data['users'] = User::all();
            $page = Input::get('page'); // Get the current page or default to 1, this is what you miss!
            $perPage = 12;
            $offset = ($page * $perPage) - $perPage;


            $data['role'] = Input::get('role');
            $search = Input::get('search');
            $name = Input::get('name');
            $country = Input::get('country');
            $city = Input::get('city');
            $industry = Input::get('industry');
            $language_skills = Input::get('language_skills');

            $department = Input::get('department');
            $function_name = Input::get('function_name');
            $company = Input::get('company');
            $timeframe = Input::get('timeframe');
            $organization_type = Input::get('organization_type');
            $contact_level = Input::get('contact_level');
            $data['search'] = $search;

            // DB::enableQueryLog();


            $users = User::with('country','industry','organization_type','career_path','career_path.industry','career_path.department','career_path.functions','role');
$private = DB::table('privacy_settings')->get();
```

How can I do that? I guess it should be something like `$private = DB::table('privacy_settings')->where('id', '=', 'city')->get();`, but this doesn't working.

So, now I get the id o the user with `{{ $user['id'] }}` , from table `Users`, column `id`.
In table `privacy_settings` I have column `user_id` which has id of users and `city` with 2 values : 0 for public, and 1 for private. I need to get these values based on every `user_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically, fetch the collection from column user_id where user_id = the id you passed in your blade. replace `$user['id']` with that value.

```
$temparr = [];
$buffer = 0;

foreach($users as $user){
    $arr = [];
    $privacy = PrivancySetting::where('user_id', $user['id'])->first();
    $city = $privacy['city'];
    if($city == 0){
        $buffer = 0;
        $arr['id'] = $user['id'];
        $arr['perm'] = $buffer;
        array_push($temparr, $arr);
    }else{
        $buffer = 1;
        $arr['id'] = $user['id'];
        $arr['perm'] = $buffer;
        array_push($temparr, $arr);
     }
}
```

Pass $temparr to your view and do a loop in it to cross check and hide what you need to hide!

Comment: Hey, shouldn't be `$users['id']` instead of `$user['id']` ? Please check updated controller

Comment: yeap, `$users['id']` i commented before you edited the question haha. but as i said, replace it with whatever variable you're using to call the userid

Comment: Yes, my bad. I saw that after your comment. But now, I got this error `Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder as array`

Comment: did you use ->first() at the end of the line?

Comment: hmmm, is there a model for your table, privacy_settings?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201069/discussion-between-andrew-and-udhayan-nair).